# How to split or device an Entry into small entries in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

[image]

Hi Guys, I'm building an app that has an Entry similar to that of tinder, does anyone have an idea on how I can achieve this. I tried creating multiple entries and move focus on the text entered but deleting is the issue as TextChaned method is only called when there is text

Comment: Hi , you can custom Entry Renderer to implement it in Native iOS.

Comment: No, TextChanged actually also called when there is no text, you can notice that there is `OldValue` and `NewValue` when text change. Perhaps you can show your code in text change part.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms , you can Custom a Entry Render  View in **iOS** to implement it .

Create a custom `Entry` :

```
public class CustomEntry : Entry
{

}
```

Then in Native iOS, create a `CustomEntryRenderer` ：

```
public class CustomEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    private UITextField textField;
    int numberCount = 6;
    nfloat itemMargin =20;
    List<UILabel> labels = new List<UILabel>();
    List<UIView> lines = new List<UIView>();
    UIControl maskView = new UIControl();

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        textField = (UITextField)this.Control;
        //textField.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Done;
        textField.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
        textField.AutocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.None;
        textField.TextColor = UIColor.Clear;
        textField.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;
        textField.EditingChanged += TextField_EditingChanged;

        UIButton maskView = new UIButton();
        maskView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        maskView.TouchUpInside += MaskView_TouchUpInside;
        textField.AddSubview(maskView);
        this.maskView = maskView;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++)
        {
            UILabel label = new UILabel();
            label.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
            label.TextColor = UIColor.DarkTextColor;
            label.Font = UIFont.FromName("PingFangSC-Regular", 41);
            textField.AddSubview(label);
            labels.Add(label);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++)
        {
            UIView line = new UIView();
            line.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Purple;
            textField.AddSubview(line);
            lines.Add(line);
        }

    }

    public override void LayoutSubviews()
    {
        base.LayoutSubviews();
        nfloat temp = textField.Bounds.Size.Width - (itemMargin * (numberCount - 1));
        nfloat w = temp / numberCount;
        nfloat x = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
        {
            x = i * (w + itemMargin);
            UILabel label = labels[i];
            label.Frame = new CGRect(x, 0, w, textField.Bounds.Size.Height);

            UIView line = lines[i];
            line.Frame = new CGRect(x, textField.Bounds.Size.Height - 1, w, 1);
        }
        maskView.Frame = textField.Bounds;

    }

    private void MaskView_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textField.BecomeFirstResponder();
    }

    private void TextField_EditingChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textField.Text.Length > numberCount)
        {
            //Range range = new Range(0, numberCount);

            textField.Text = textField.Text.Substring(0, numberCount);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++)
        {
            UILabel label = labels[i];
            if(i< textField.Text.Length)
            {
                label.Text = textField.Text.Substring(i, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                label.Text = "";
            }
        }

        if (textField.Text.Length >= numberCount)
        {
            textField.ResignFirstResponder();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally , you can use it in Xaml :

```
<ProjectNameSpace:CustomEntry x:Name="customEntry" WidthRequest="300" />
```

The effect :

[image]

Comment: @Java_Dude Glad be helpful .Thanks for marking it in advance when you have time .